# What is a util in Java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and I would like to know what a Util is. Can anyone help me? I mean the imports for example: `java.util.Scanner`, what is a util?

Comment: This is one second of googling: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html > Package java.util
Contains the collections framework, legacy collection classes, event model, date and time facilities, internationalization, and miscellaneous utility classes (a string tokenizer, a random-number generator, and a bit array).

Comment: Util for _utilities_

Comment: util is an abbreviation for "utility"

Comment: And it is a package name also, whee `Scanner` is the class name inside the package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"util" is an abbreviation of utilities. The `java.util` package contains classes which although they aren't a "must" for working with java (like the `java.lang` package, they provide functionality for common usecases which are often encountered.

To quote [the package's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html):

> Contains the collections framework, legacy collection classes, event model, date and time facilities, internationalization, and miscellaneous utility classes (a string tokenizer, a random-number generator, and a bit array).